# How dangerous are cracked teeth?

Tags: dentistry, cracked-broken-tooth

Common accidents can lead to tooth injuries. A tooth that has fallen out obviously needs a dentist, but cracked teeth are on a line between important and ignorable. How does this type of injury affect the patients' health? What are the potential consequences of leaving a cracked tooth untreated?

[image: Example of cracked tooth]

Comment: Anecdotal evidence, but I can share my experience. I had a seizure (brought on by a 20+ hour migraine) and faceplanted on a hardwood floor, shearing off the bottom half of a front tooth that was protruding out of the line of the rest.  After going to the hospital and getting other things taken care of, a dental student sealed it. The sealant did crack and fall out later.  Since then my dentist asks if I want it fixed, but since it isn't a cutting hazard and I'm keeping it clean they said its only a cosmetic issue. So as said below: check with your dentist, and they can suggest the right action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More dangerous than healthy teeth, but not impossible to live with. A cracked tooth has a higher risk of breaking, is less resistant to tooth decay, heat, cold, acid etc. The 2 most dangerous situations I can imagine:

- If the weakened tooth breaks apart, its parts can be as dangerous as shards of glass in the mouth.
- If the injury leads to osteomyelitis, it might require a surgery.

I'm not a doctor, I'm just guessing: if your tooth is cracked, **see your dentist ASAP**, as each case is unique.

(The photo in the question is my cracked tooth. I had an accident almost a year ago, landed my face on concrete, visited my dentist, used 25 g Elmex gel as she recommended. I still don't use this tooth, so fortunatelly it's still in its place and is painless.)

Comment: +1 for *see your dentist immediately*. This is the most important thing the OP should do right now!